# Transition by zoom in ? ( HTML / CSS / Javascript / jQuery / .. ? )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website with a grid of elements that scrolls down. Something very similar than this example:

[image]

I would like that, when you click on an element, it zooms in on this element, the other elements disappear, and next to the chosen element's image, some text is displayed. And when you exit this view, the text disappears, and unzoom to the initial view with the grid of all elements.

I don't know how this effect is called - if it ever has a name - and I am having a hard time figuring out how it could be done.. jQuery ? CSS animation ?

I am open to any leads ! Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a piece of code with jQuery. You can achieve your goal with many ways but here is one.

You can use `scale()` CSS3 properties to make the zoom on the image and `hide()` with jQuery to hide the other ones while you `click()` on one.

If you can't find a solution with these hints, I've made an example of what you wants [right here](https://jsfiddle.net/tnhspq7t/5/)

Comment: that is great thanks ! For the record I had also found this jQuery plugin that seems to do the job.Cheers

Comment: After some coding, the mix of both your solution and the jQuery library I found ( called Zoomooz ) works great. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create new div on click with absolute position and display it on front of other elements(bigger z-index)